# Release Version of iOS App Is Hitting DEBUG Flags

Tags: ios, xcode, debug-symbols

In my schema, I have specified Release as the build type:

[image]

In my code I have some checks to see if it's in DEBUG or RELEASE. However it always hits the DEBUG (line 125 in the example below):

[image]

Do you know what I might be missing when I build for release so it stops hitting the DEBUG flags?

Comment: Have you checked the value of the DEBUG symbol in your a release schema?

Comment: @AliBeadle Where would I be able to confirm that value in the schema? I've looked under a number of sub menus but don't see a specification.

Comment: OK, difficult to do in a comment, I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional compilation like this does not depend on the Build Configuration but the presence of the DEBUG flag within that configuration.

Go to your project's build settings and search for 'flag'. Look under 'Swift Compiler - Custom Flags' and then 'Active Compilation Conditions': each build configuration is then listed and the flag DEBUG should be present where you want your debug code to appear but absent where you do not.

[image]